# Ionic default activity background color

Tags: css, ionic-framework, android-activity, sass

Whenever I start the app, I get WHITE empty background when waiting for app to load.
Thats very annoying.
Although I set app to use DARK theme, which is working fine, I still have that white screen, when app is loading.

Is there a way to fix this ?

Comment: you want to change the color or add content to it ? or you just want the app to lunch without showing that?

Answer (score 0):

That white background is likely just the browser before your HTML and/or CSS areloaded. I see three options:

1. Show a splash screen
2. Add an inline style to the body tag (`style="background-color:black"`)
3. Improve your app's loading time, e.g. by optimizing and/or splitting up your CSS and JS.